# asymptotic-complexity - Calculate steps of primitive operations

Tags: algorithm, bubble-sort, asymptotic-complexity

I've some difficulties understanding how i should calculate the primitive operations of the following algorithm.

[image]

I know that the calculations of the steps is somehow like this:

(1) = 1 step: Assignment

(2) = 1 step: Assignment

(3) = 3+(n-1) steps: 3 comparisons which undergoes (n-1) times

(4) = 1 step: Assignment

(5) = 2+(n-2): Assignment and comparison which undergoes (n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1=(n-1)n/2 times

(6) = 3 steps: two array, one comparisons [<] and one operation [-]

(7) = 4 steps: two array, one operation [-] and function call to swap wich is step 3 n(1)

(8) = 2 steps: Assignment and addition operation

I can deduce that the worst-case scenario is (n^2+n+2n+2) = O(n^2) because the worst-case is when the list is ordered with the first value as the larges and the last value as the smallest which results as a sum from i=0 to n (i-1).

Also the best-case scenario when the list is already ordered which as a result means that the list will run as a constant speed.

My problem is to find how to gather the primitive operations from the algorithm so i can on my own prove this with the definition of Ordo by calculate c and n_0.

Answer (score 0):

When someone says that a sorting algorithm has a particular time-complexity they usually refer to the number of comparisons needed. As you have already done you need to count the number of comparisons between elements and figure out the constants.

Comment: I still don't understand how, could i be presented with an example?

Comment: In the algorithm that you mention the comparisons happen in step (6). The number of comparisons will be n * (n - 1) / 2 as you mentioned. Since n * (n - 1) / 2 <= c * n^2 for all c >= 1/2, you can call it O(n^2).